# How to space every collapse range vscode?

Tags: android-studio, visual-studio-code

How to space every collapse range vscode ?

What I call the "collapse zone" is the part of the code that can be folded or unfolded. In the example image, these are the downward-pointing arrows next to the line numbers.

I don't want them spaced out in the code, but in the vscode interface.

Vscode image : [vscode example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qT3Ft.png)

Like android-studio do : [android-studio example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vEcjL.png)